# Clustering topics and naming the cluster in Python

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, topic-modeling

I have millions of topics in my data. These topics are one to 12 words. For instance 'Cancer Biology and Genetics' could be one topic and 'Regenerative medicines' could be another. I want to create clusters of similar topics and name them. I tried BERT+K-Means to cluster these topics and it works fine. I don't know much about NLP and want to use the best approach to this. I also do not have a way to name these clusters in a way that it makes sense and represents the cluster. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a standard automated method for naming clusters - part of the work in doing topic modeling and unsupervised learning in general is to do post-analysis and decide whether the topics/clusters make sense and what they "are about". There are definitely approaches in research, however, *e.g.* [Automatic Labelling of Topics with Neural Embeddings](https://github.com/sb1992/NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-).

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might be able to cheat and give the list of words to a generative AI model (*i.e.* just ask ChatGPT) for suggestions to start / get some initial results quickly.